# Videos in Stream (SharePoint)

Tags: media-streaming

Currently we use Stream (Classic) and this holds videos which we share to multiple Teams/classes in Microsoft Teams for Education.

I can't see a way to share videos in the new Stream/SharePoint to multiple Teams. Am I missing something? Thanks

I could add a website link to a special Team hosting the videos but that isn't honouring read-only settings.

Answer (score 1):

From the new Stream v2 listing page, you can share to Microsoft Teams by clicking the ellipsis > Share > Teams

[image]

Alternatively, you can copy a link and paste that in to the Teams channel.

To manage access, you can either go to the location of the video in SharePoint and ensure that the teams have access to that area/video or you can open the video in Stream > Click the Share button and select "Manage access".

Comment: Thanks Callum. 

It's hard to explain for anyone who may be reading this and who hasn't used Microsoft Teams for Education. It works a bit differently from regular Teams.

Comment: If a course ie Team runs in April and May and has a unit ie Channel, in Stream (Classic) I share video 123 to April and to May. In the Team/course I add a link to Videos and all the videos shared to the Group/Channel appear. 

So that is easy - and a changed video will be available in both. The downside is that a changed video may no longer match other material. SO.... I may decide it is better to hold videos in each Team/course in Stream (SharePoint).

Comment: This is pushing me towards the 'duplicate' solution: On Microsoft page: Before, you would create a group or channel in Stream (Classic) and add your videos into the gro…
Now, the groups and channels concepts from Stream (Classic) does not carry forward into Stream (on SharePoint). Instead, you’ll organize your videos the same way you would any other files.

Comment: I actually think Microsoft recommend creating a communication site and then using that to store videos for a particular purpose e.g. you could have a Health & Safety video site and customise it for your orgs users with featured videos on the home page etc.